# RFC 6520 support in JDK API

Tags: java

Does Java support RFC 6520? If yes, then from which update is it available? RFC 6520 is better known as (DTLS) Heartbeat Extension.

Comment: Why do you think that java has the base protocol at all?

Comment: [Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) seem to have support for heartbeat messages and RFC 6520.

Comment: @ChrisMantle, yes BC API has the support , this brings the question do the java API also support